# Group by interval of datetime using pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have data

```
data    id  url size    domain  subdomain
13/Jun/2016:06:27:26    30055   https://api.weather.com/v1/geocode/55.740002/37.610001/aggregate.json?apiKey=e45ff1b7c7bda231216c7ab7c33509b8&products=conditionsshort,fcstdaily10short,fcsthourly24short,nowlinks  3929    weather.com api.weather.com
13/Jun/2016:06:27:26    30055   https://api.weather.com/v1/geocode/54.720001/20.469999/aggregate.json?apiKey=e45ff1b7c7bda231216c7ab7c33509b8&products=conditionsshort,fcstdaily10short,fcsthourly24short,nowlinks  3845    weather.com api.weather.com
13/Jun/2016:06:27:27    3845    https://api.weather.com/v1/geocode/54.970001/73.370003/aggregate.json?apiKey=e45ff1b7c7bda231216c7ab7c33509b8&products=conditionsshort,fcstdaily10short,fcsthourly24short,nowlinks  30055   weather.com api.weather.com
13/Jun/2016:06:27:27    30055   https://api.weather.com/v1/geocode/59.919998/30.219999/aggregate.json?apiKey=e45ff1b7c7bda231216c7ab7c33509b8&products=conditionsshort,fcstdaily10short,fcsthourly24short,nowlinks  3914    weather.com api.weather.com
13/Jun/2016:06:27:28    30055   https://facebook.com    4005    facebook.com    facebook.com
```

I need to group it with interval 5 minutes. 
Desire output

```
 data   id  url size    domain  subdomain
13/Jun/2016:06:27:26    30055   https://api.weather.com/v1/geocode/55.740002/37.610001/aggregate.json?apiKey=e45ff1b7c7bda231216c7ab7c33509b8&products=conditionsshort,fcstdaily10short,fcsthourly24short,nowlinks  3929    weather.com api.weather.com
13/Jun/2016:06:27:27    3845    https://api.weather.com/v1/geocode/54.970001/73.370003/aggregate.json?apiKey=e45ff1b7c7bda231216c7ab7c33509b8&products=conditionsshort,fcstdaily10short,fcsthourly24short,nowlinks  30055   weather.com api.weather.com
13/Jun/2016:06:27:28    30055   https://facebook.com    4005    facebook.com    facebook.com
```

I need to groupby `id, subdomain` and establish interval `5min`
I try use

```
print df.groupby([df['data'],pd.TimeGrouper(freq='Min')])
```

to group first with minute, but it return `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse `data` using `pd.to_datetime()` with appropriate `format` settings and use the result as `index`. Then `.groupby()` while resampling to `5Min` intervals:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.data, format='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('5Min')).apply(lambda x: x.groupby(['id', 'subdomain']).first())

                                                           data  \
data                id    subdomain                               
2016-06-13 06:25:00 3845  api.weather.com  13/Jun/2016:06:27:27   
                    30055 api.weather.com  13/Jun/2016:06:27:26   
                          facebook.com     13/Jun/2016:06:27:28   

                                                                                         url  \
data                id    subdomain                                                            
2016-06-13 06:25:00 3845  api.weather.com  https://api.weather.com/v1/geocode/54.970001/7...   
                    30055 api.weather.com  https://api.weather.com/v1/geocode/55.740002/3...   
                          facebook.com                                  https://facebook.com   

                                            size        domain  
data                id    subdomain                             
2016-06-13 06:25:00 3845  api.weather.com  30055   weather.com  
                    30055 api.weather.com   3929   weather.com  
                          facebook.com      4005  facebook.com
```

Comment: It delete url to next second

Comment: Sorry had overlooked some detail in your question - see update now including `'id'` and `'subdomain'`.

Comment: It looks very well! I want ask you, if I have domain, that I don't want to consider, I want to see all visits, Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

Note to convert to datetime you can pass the following format:

```
df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'], format="%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
```

Now you can use the groupby:

```
In [11]: df1 = df.set_index("data")

In [12]: df1.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("5Min")).sum()
Out[12]:
                         id   size
data
2016-06-13 06:25:00  124065  45748
```

This is better written as a resample:

```
In [13]: df1.resample("5Min").sum()
Out[13]:
                         id   size
data
2016-06-13 06:25:00  124065  45748
```

Comment: I need to get url that use at first in every 5 minute to every id

Comment: You can use: `df1.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("5Min")).agg({"url": "first"})`.

Comment: but it is to all id, I need to consider that

Comment: oh, I see, there was a typo in your question, but that makes sense: `df1.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper("5Min"), "id"]).agg({"url": "first"})`

Answer (score 0):

you need to `set_index` first
check that `df.index` is a **Datetimeindex**. If not, that's the cause of the error